# Richfaces valueChangeEvent on input not working

Tags: jsf, richfaces, javabeans, ajax4jsf

I'm trying to use an richfaces inputNumberSlider or inputNumberSpinner.

The problem is I'm not able to update the values in my beans.

Here are the 2 solutions I tried:

**1)**

```
<rich:inputNumberSlider value="#{skinningBean.currentSkin.topBar.bannerXOffset}"
valueChangeListener="#{skinningBean.valueBannerXOffSetChangeListener}"
onchange="A4J.findForm(this).submit()">
</rich:inputNumberSlider>
```

In the bean:

```
public void valueBannerXOffSetChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    System.out.println("x value changed");
    currentSkin.getTopBar().setBannerXOffset((Integer) event.getNewValue());
}
```

**2)**

```
<rich:inputNumberSpinner value="#{skinningBean.currentSkin.topBar.bannerYOffset}">
  <a4j:ajax event="change" render="preview" oncomplete="initSlider()" />
</rich:inputNumberSpinner>
```

This should just call my setter in the bean. I havw written two setter one which takes a String and one which takes an Integer. None of them is called

Although I need an a4j supprt anyway to rerender my items, a working solution for number 2 would be preferred

Comment: The primary reasons for this behaviour are 1. a conversion error 2. validation failure 3. Form not being successfully submitted. You need to eliminate all three. Check your browser's javascript console (on the network tab) for confirmation

Answer (score -1):

Try the following first, once you get it working you can add the **oncomplete** part:

```
<rich:inputNumberSpinner value="#{skinningBean.currentSkin.topBar.bannerYOffset}">
  <a4j:ajax event="onchange" render="preview" action="#{bean.valueBannerXOffSetChangeListener}" />
</rich:inputNumberSpinner>
```

Possible you will need to redefine your bean function to not receive parameters.

Reference:
https://community.jboss.org/message/588944#588944

Comment: 1: You messed up X and Y values, but nvm ;)
2: there is no onchange event. It has to be "change"
3: why should I redfeine the method with no parameters? That sounds kinda weird. I need an ValueChangeEvent
4: still no success

Comment: Okay I guess you mean I should call the setter, but that's not working either. -1 for just copying code (which isn't even the same) without understanding

Comment: I was proposing to call the bean method as an action, avoiding using listener explicitly and changing the event from "change" to "unchange".

Comment: There is no onchange event for a4j:ajax. It was supported by a4j:support which is outdated for quite a long time. And it isn't necessary to call the method via an action although getter and setter are called automatically, as you can see in my second approach. This is working fine for every h:input  etc

Comment: According to source code, it is the same to call change or onchange. <cdk:object name="onchange" type="String"
value="#{convertToString(RenderKitUtils.getAttributeAndBehaviorsValue(facesContext, component, RenderKitUtils.attributes().generic(**'onchange', 'onchange', 'change', 'valueChange'**).first()))}" /> Therefore, that is not the problem. Can you please post the whole code of your bean?

Comment: @RodmarConde event="onchange" would fail on runtime because JSF checks for presence of the specified event in javax.faces.component.behavior.ClientBehaviorHolder#getEventNames of the component. Also there is no action attribute supported by a4j:ajax, it should be listener="#{...}", and there is no need to remove the argument (in fact listener attribute expects "a public method that takes an ActionEvent parameter, with a return type of void, or a public method that takes no arguments with a return type of void").